# Unwanted lines across geometry

Tags: modeling

So I was using the boolean difference modifier and this happened...
[image: Annoying line thing]

So I have three questions, what is this annoying line that should not be there called, how do I get rid of it ,and how do I prevent it from happening?

File here:[image]

Comment: That line is an artifact cause by an NGon (face with more than 4 sides), and you can get rid of it by cleaning up your geometry (quad based mesh , good topology, sane normals), and you can avoid it in the future by leaning good modeling techniques proper for use with meshes, instead of using Booleans

Comment: How can I make that shape without boolean?

Comment: I don't know, I can't see what shape that is, but [this](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com) might help

Comment: Ngons and non-planar geometry: bad combination... You need more subdivisions to smooth the surface or have all of the vertices be on the same plane.

Comment: as @cegaton says, you need to make that surface absolutely coplanar: you could try something like this: select all ngon "countour" vertices, then scale on the local Z to zero (SZZ0) They could change a bit shape, but they should become coplanar.